# Not in to not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, exists

I have a 'not in' that I am trying to turn into a 'not exists' within the where clause of my select

I tried switching the bare minimum but nothing was populated (it did execute

```
where  [a] not in (
select 
    [a] 
from table
group by [a]
having count(*) > 1) -- Ignores Records with duplicate data
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as:

```
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where ?.a = t2.a
                  group by t2.a
                  having count(*) > 1
                 )
```

Often, though, this would be looking for *another* reference to the same value in a table in the query.  If so, eschew the aggregation:

```
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where ?.a = t2.a and ?.id <> t2.id
                 )
```